# Ruby Timeout and Sleeping Threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

When inside a sleeping thread, does Ruby Timeout still count down?

I would like to have some threads timeout after a length of time, but only if the thread has been actively running.

Answer (score 0):

As it might be easily read in [`Timeout#timeout`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) source code, there is no magic: another thread is being started, slept and terminated.

So, the answer to your question is: the timeout is the real time timeout and it does not depend on any other thread lifecycles.